# Interaction between SL and hosted web page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, silverlight, communication

We've been working on a SL application for a while now, but are thinking of starting a new MVC app with pieces of the existing SL app (complex tasks) hosted on those pages. In order to make that decision, I'm trying to find some info that could help us.

The part where we have to host the SL-app in our pages is pretty straightforward, but what is harder to find is how we can communicate between our MVC app and SL app. I know there are `InitParams` that you can pass into the SL app when it is initialised, but is there any way you can communicate after the init phase (either from MVC --> SL or SL --> MVC)? I've read that in SL, you have access to the DOM and can use JS to access the DOM too, but haven't found any examples or more information about that.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight => JS : `HtmlPage.Window.Invoke` [Doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.browser.scriptobject.invoke%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

JS => Silverlight : [Sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/293515/Calling-Silverlight-Method-from-Javascript-and-Jav)

Comment: Having a go at it, i'll update shortly. Update: seems to do the job properly.